# Fibonacci nth term formula with BigInteger in java

Tags: java, formula, fibonacci, biginteger

I'm trying to solve the nth term of fibonacci series based on [this](https://math.hmc.edu/funfacts/fibonacci-number-formula/) formula.

Here is my code :

```java
public BigInteger getFibonacciNumber(int index) {
        final Instant start = Instant.now();

        if (index == 0) return BigInteger.ZERO;
        if (index == 1) return BigInteger.ONE;

        BigDecimal phi1 = new BigDecimal("5");
        phi1 = phi1.sqrt(MathContext.DECIMAL128);
        BigDecimal phi2 = phi1.subtract(BigDecimal.ONE);
        phi1 = phi1.add(BigDecimal.ONE);
        phi1 = phi1.divide(new BigDecimal("2"), 8, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
        phi2 = phi2.divide(new BigDecimal("2"), 8, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);


        BigDecimal p1 = phi1.pow(index);
        BigDecimal p2 = phi2.pow(index);
        p1 = p1.subtract(p2);
        BigDecimal sqrt5 = BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.sqrt(5));
        p1 = p1.divide(sqrt5, 8, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
        Log.infov(
                "Fibonacci number for index {0} computed in {1}",
                index, Duration.between(start, Instant.now()));
        return p1.toBigInteger();
    }
```

But I have problems, for example, with the 100th term, I expect `354224848179261915075` when I get `354224875546939407559`. I think that there's a problem with the scale or the rounding method of the BigDecimal but I don't know how to resolve it. Do you have any idea?

Comment: 1) division by `2` does not need rounding (and we could use `BigDecimal.TWO`); 2) `Math.sqrt` is not precise enough, why not use the previously calculated value using `BigDecimal.sqrt`? 3) not relevant for such index, but `phi2` does not correspond the posted link formula (subtracting ONE from `sqrtr(5)`, instead of ONE minus `sqrt(5)`); 4) not an error, but the code is a bit hard to read or to compare with the formula  (better naming or intermediate values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two problems regarding the precision of your calculations. First, the divide needs a higher scale value. Second, in the end you cast the result to a `BigInteger`, which simply cuts off the decimal places. You need to round the value to an integer value first. I also restructured your method a little:

```
public static BigInteger getFibonacciNumber(int index) {
    if (index == 0) return BigInteger.ZERO;
    if (index == 1) return BigInteger.ONE;

    BigDecimal sqrt5 = new BigDecimal(5).sqrt(MathContext.DECIMAL128);

    BigDecimal PHI = BigDecimal.ONE.add(sqrt5).divide(new BigDecimal(2), RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    BigDecimal phi = BigDecimal.ONE.subtract(sqrt5).divide(new BigDecimal(2), RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

    BigDecimal p1 = PHI.pow(index, MathContext.DECIMAL128);
    BigDecimal p2 = phi.pow(index, MathContext.DECIMAL128);
    p1 = p1.subtract(p2);

    p1 = p1.divide(sqrt5, 50, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

    return p1.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toBigInteger();
}
```

If you input 100 the result is as expected:

```
354224848179261915075
```

Edit: Had to make the precision even higher as the result was still a little bit off

Comment: Thank you! I hope it looks better now. I added all your suggestions besides `BigDecimal.TWO` as it is limited to Java 19.

Comment: The link OP posted stated that `phi = -1 / PHI` can also be used.